# MongoDB 4.0 жрет всю память и падает

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Когда стояла mongodb 3.6 и node.js 9.x все было замечательно, все работало 3-6 месяцев и никаких неполадок небыло.
Недавно решил обновить все и начались проблемы:
Сайт размещен на ВПС debian 9, 4GB ОЗУ, 2 ядра.
После обновления спустя сутки сайт уходит в даун, выяснилось что упал mongod, потому что всю память сожрал.
После увеличил ОЗУ до 8GB, все успешно работало 2 дня, потом опять тоже самое, приходится перезагружать сервер.

Node.js - v10.7.0
MongoDB - 4.0.0

Mongod.conf

```
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
  wiredTiger:
    engineConfig:
       cacheSizeGB: 6
```

cacheSizeGB добавлял после и не помогло

Syslog

```
Jul 28 08:56:54 SiteName dhclient[674]: DHCPREQUEST of xx.xx.xxx.186 on eth0 to xxx.xx.1.1 port 67
Jul 28 08:56:54 SiteName dhclient[674]: DHCPACK of xx.xx.xxx.186 from 172.31.1.1
Jul 28 08:56:54 SiteName dhclient[674]: bound to xx.xx.xxx.186 -- renewal in 36837 seconds.
Jul 28 09:00:01 SiteName CRON[16647]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/node /var/www/SiteName.ru/bin/cron/synonyms.js >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331671.923612] node invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x24280ca(GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE|__GFP_ZERO), nodemask=0, order=0, oom_score_adj=0
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331671.926532] node cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331671.927797] CPU: 1 PID: 16649 Comm: node Not tainted 4.9.0-7-amd64 #1 Debian 4.9.110-1
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331671.930045] Hardware name: Hetzner vServer, BIOS 20171111 11/11/2017
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331671.931869]  0000000000000000 ffffffff97530644 ffffa70f811ffcf0 ffff8c66a600a800
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331671.933872]  ffffffff97403b30 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000c9754f4c9
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331671.936081]  ffff8c66a8f5c0c0 ffffffff973892d7 ffffffffc02d86a5 00000000ffffffff
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331671.938199] Call Trace:
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331671.939114]  [<ffffffff97530644>] ? dump_stack+0x5c/0x78
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331671.940716]  [<ffffffff97403b30>] ? dump_header+0x78/0x1fd
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331671.942091]  [<ffffffff973892d7>] ? get_page_from_freelist+0x3f7/0xb20
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331671.943796]  [<ffffffffc02d86a5>] ? virtballoon_oom_notify+0x25/0x70 [virtio_balloon]
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331671.945691]  [<ffffffff9738524a>] ? oom_kill_process+0x21a/0x3e0
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331671.947509]  [<ffffffff97384ecd>] ? oom_badness+0xed/0x170
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331671.949058]  [<ffffffff973856e1>] ? out_of_memory+0x111/0x470
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331671.950435]  [<ffffffff9738a957>] ? __alloc_pages_slowpath+0xbb7/0xbf0
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331671.952418]  [<ffffffff9738ab91>] ? __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x201/0x260
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331671.954490]  [<ffffffff973dd39e>] ? alloc_pages_vma+0xae/0x260
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331671.956408]  [<ffffffff973b8b75>] ? handle_mm_fault+0xf85/0x1280
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331671.958474]  [<ffffffff973c223b>] ? mprotect_fixup+0x14b/0x280
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331671.960235]  [<ffffffff97261015>] ? __do_page_fault+0x255/0x4f0
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331671.961797]  [<ffffffff97815fc8>] ? async_page_fault+0x28/0x30
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331671.963560] Mem-Info:
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331671.964188] active_anon:1929006 inactive_anon:20527 isolated_anon:0
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331671.964188]  active_file:23 inactive_file:40 isolated_file:0
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331671.964188]  unevictable:0 dirty:23 writeback:1 unstable:0
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331671.964188]  slab_reclaimable:3124 slab_unreclaimable:4679
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331671.964188]  mapped:1217 shmem:20680 pagetables:5547 bounce:0
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331671.964188]  free:25595 free_pcp:30 free_cma:0
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331671.972611] Node 0 active_anon:7716024kB inactive_anon:82108kB active_file:92kB inactive_file:160kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB mapped:4868kB dirty:92kB writeback:4kB shmem:82720kB shmem_thp: 0kB shmem_pmdmapped: 0kB anon_thp: 0kB writeback_tmp:0kB unstable:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? no
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331671.980534] Node 0 DMA free:15908kB min:132kB low:164kB high:196kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB writepending:0kB present:15992kB managed:15908kB mlocked:0kB slab_reclaimable:0kB slab_unreclaimable:0kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331671.988558] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 2974 7760 7760 7760
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331671.990193] Node 0 DMA32 free:44928kB min:25848kB low:32308kB high:38768kB active_anon:2972344kB inactive_anon:32828kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:92kB unevictable:0kB writepending:4kB present:3129200kB managed:3063632kB mlocked:0kB slab_reclaimable:960kB slab_unreclaimable:1904kB kernel_stack:128kB pagetables:8040kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:120kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331671.999852] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 4785 4785 4785
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.001358] Node 0 Normal free:41544kB min:41596kB low:51992kB high:62388kB active_anon:4743540kB inactive_anon:49280kB active_file:88kB inactive_file:160kB unevictable:0kB writepending:92kB present:5046272kB managed:4905432kB mlocked:0kB slab_reclaimable:11536kB slab_unreclaimable:16812kB kernel_stack:2848kB pagetables:14148kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.011717] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0 0
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.013776] Node 0 DMA: 1*4kB (U) 0*8kB 0*16kB 1*32kB (U) 2*64kB (U) 1*128kB (U) 1*256kB (U) 0*512kB 1*1024kB (U) 1*2048kB (M) 3*4096kB (M) = 15908kB
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.019758] Node 0 DMA32: 216*4kB (UME) 192*8kB (UME) 169*16kB (UME) 187*32kB (UME) 73*64kB (UME) 34*128kB (UME) 17*256kB (UE) 10*512kB (UME) 1*1024kB (E) 3*2048kB (UE) 2*4096kB (M) = 44944kB
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.027118] Node 0 Normal: 873*4kB (UME) 618*8kB (UE) 367*16kB (UME) 260*32kB (UME) 140*64kB (UME) 46*128kB (UME) 14*256kB (UME) 1*512kB (E) 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 41572kB
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.033850] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=1048576kB
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.037183] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.040524] 20785 total pagecache pages
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.042589] 0 pages in swap cache
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.044689] Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.047591] Free swap  = 0kB
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.049456] Total swap = 0kB
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.051438] 2047866 pages RAM
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.053354] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.055177] 51623 pages reserved
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.056987] 0 pages hwpoisoned
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.059058] [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes nr_pmds swapents oom_score_adj name
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.062671] [  468]     0   468    15621     1189      29       3        0             0 systemd-journal
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.066137] [  498]     0   498    11377      203      22       3        0         -1000 systemd-udevd
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.069202] [  524]   100   524    31821      123      30       3        0             0 systemd-timesyn
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.072599] [  674]     0   674     5087      259      13       3        0             0 dhclient
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.075832] [  809]     0   809    11620      150      26       3        0             0 systemd-logind
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.079479] [  812]   106   812    11283      111      27       3        0          -900 dbus-daemon
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.083417] [  817]     0   817     7400       77      19       3        0             0 cron
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.086849] [  819]     0   819    62529      304      28       3        0             0 rsyslogd
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.090156] [  840]     0   840    17486      195      38       3        0         -1000 sshd
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.092995] [  849]     0   849     3223       34      12       3        0             0 agetty
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.096574] [  850]     0   850     5630       70      15       3        0             0 qemu-ga
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.100032] [  851]     0   851     3569       39      12       3        0             0 agetty
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.103196] [  873]     0   873    16038      258      24       3        0             0 nginx
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.106173] [  922]   108   922    16627     1059      25       3        0             0 nginx
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.109558] [  926]   108   926    16200      549      24       3        0             0 nginx
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.112610] [  927]   108   927    16039      309      23       3        0             0 nginx
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.116217] [  957]     0   957    31152      466      60       3        0             0 proftpd
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.119242] [ 1151]   105  1151    14039      187      30       3        0             0 exim4
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.122190] [ 1158]     0  1158   232992     6588     100      60        0             0 PM2 v2.10.4: Go
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.125398] [ 7026]   111  7026  2046636  1763814    3577      10        0             0 mongod
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.128446] [ 9043]     0  9043   326382    24448     380     166        0             0 node /var/www/f
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.131995] [16635]     0 16635    12216      110      28       3        0             0 cron
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.135032] [16636]     0 16636    12216      110      28       3        0             0 cron
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.137970] [16637]     0 16637    12216      110      28       3        0             0 cron
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.141408] [16638]     0 16638    12216      110      28       3        0             0 cron
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.144878] [16639]     0 16639    12216      110      28       3        0             0 cron
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.148028] [16640]     0 16640    12216      110      28       3        0             0 cron
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.150997] [16641]     0 16641     1072       19       8       3        0             0 sh
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.153821] [16642]     0 16642     1072       19       8       3        0             0 sh
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.156739] [16643]     0 16643     1072       19       8       3        0             0 sh
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.159823] [16644]     0 16644     1072       19       8       3        0             0 sh
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.162419] [16645]     0 16645     1072       18       7       3        0             0 sh
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.165206] [16646]     0 16646   243203    21939     141      77        0             0 node
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.168140] [16647]     0 16647     1072       19       7       3        0             0 sh
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.170081] [16648]     0 16648   243205    21780     140      78        0             0 node
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.172854] [16649]     0 16649   242642    20835     128      59        0             0 node
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.175412] [16650]     0 16650   242622    21027     120      59        0             0 node
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.178331] [16659]     0 16659   242620    21022     124      59        0             0 node
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.181423] [16660]     0 16660   243211    21810     137      77        0             0 node
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.184308] Out of memory: Kill process 7026 (mongod) score 885 or sacrifice child
Jul 28 09:00:05 SiteName kernel: [331672.187084] Killed process 7026 (mongod) total-vm:8186544kB, anon-rss:7055256kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
Jul 28 09:00:06 SiteName systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Jul 28 09:00:06 SiteName systemd[1]: mongod.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 28 09:00:06 SiteName systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
```

Mongod.log

```
До этого  лог обычных запросов и ничего более

2018-07-28T09:49:08.113+0300 I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2018-07-28T09:49:08.323+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=826 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=SiteName
2018-07-28T09:49:08.323+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.0
2018-07-28T09:49:08.323+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 3b07af3d4f471ae89e8186d33bbb1d5259597d51
2018-07-28T09:49:08.323+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017
2018-07-28T09:49:08.323+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2018-07-28T09:49:08.323+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2018-07-28T09:49:08.323+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2018-07-28T09:49:08.323+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: debian92
2018-07-28T09:49:08.323+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2018-07-28T09:49:08.323+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2018-07-28T09:49:08.323+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", port: 27017 }, processManagement: { timeZoneInfo: "/usr/share/zoneinfo" }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb", journal: { enabled: true }, wiredTiger: { engineConfig: { cacheSizeGB: 6.0 } } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
2018-07-28T09:49:08.323+0300 W STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdown - /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock is not empty.
2018-07-28T09:49:08.324+0300 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected data files in /var/lib/mongodb created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2018-07-28T09:49:08.324+0300 W STORAGE  [initandlisten] Recovering data from the last clean checkpoint.
2018-07-28T09:49:08.324+0300 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] 
2018-07-28T09:49:08.324+0300 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
2018-07-28T09:49:08.324+0300 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
2018-07-28T09:49:08.324+0300 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=6144M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
2018-07-28T09:49:10.581+0300 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1532760550:581633][826:0x7f99c56a99c0], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 794/47914112
2018-07-28T09:49:10.581+0300 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1532760550:581954][826:0x7f99c56a99c0], txn-recover: Recovering log 794 through 795
2018-07-28T09:49:10.884+0300 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1532760550:884388][826:0x7f99c56a99c0], file:sizeStorer.wt, txn-recover: Recovering log 795 through 795
2018-07-28T09:49:11.015+0300 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1532760551:15756][826:0x7f99c56a99c0], file:sizeStorer.wt, txn-recover: Set global recovery timestamp: 0
2018-07-28T09:49:11.127+0300 I RECOVERY [initandlisten] WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp. Ts: Timestamp(0, 0)
2018-07-28T09:49:11.295+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2018-07-28T09:49:11.295+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2018-07-28T09:49:11.295+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2018-07-28T09:49:11.295+0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2018-07-28T09:49:11.508+0300 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/var/lib/mongodb/diagnostic.data'
2018-07-28T09:49:11.514+0300 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2018-07-28T09:49:11.905+0300 I CONTROL  [free_mon] Free Monitoring is Enabled. Frequency: 60 seconds
2018-07-28T09:49:12.015+0300 I FTDC     [ftdc] Unclean full-time diagnostic data capture shutdown detected, found interim file, some metrics may have been lost. OK
2018-07-28T09:49:12.573+0300 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52684 #1 (1 connection now open)
2018-07-28T09:49:12.580+0300 I NETWORK  [conn1] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:52684 conn1: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "3.1.1" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "linux", architecture: "x64", version: "4.9.0-7-amd64" }, platform: "Node.js v10.7.0, LE, mongodb-core: 3.1.0" }
2018-07-28T09:49:12.601+0300 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52688 #2 (2 connections now open)
2018-07-28T09:49:12.605+0300 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52692 #3 (3 connections now open)
2018-07-28T09:49:12.607+0300 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52696 #4 (4 connections now open)
2018-07-28T09:49:12.610+0300 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52700 #5 (5 connections now open)
```

Mongostat (после перезагрузки сервера спустя пол часа)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По mongostat видно как потихоньку растет используемая память

Top (после перезагрузки сервера спустя час)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Из syslog-а вижу что монга не сама по себе упала, а ее прибил oom killer.

Эти логи были после того как добавил `cacheSizeGB: 6` ? 
А какой размер базы(или баз)?
Как по мне так `cacheSizeGB: 6` многовато, если всего 8ГБ памяти. С таким размером кеша вполне вероятно, что после того, как памяти стало не хватать, oom увидел процесс монги, который больше всех отжирает памяти, и убил его.

Про размер кэша по дефолту можно посмотреть здесь: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/#memory-use

Я думаю что для начала стоит убрать `cacheSizeGB: 6` (тогда размер кэша будет 3ГБ).

Временно oom для монги можно попробовать отключить так

```
echo "-1000" > /proc/`pidof mangod`/oom_score_adj
```

Судя по top-у я так понимаю что само nodejs приложение работает на этой же машине?

В логах время 9:00, падения в это время происходят обычно?
В это время не может быть сильно роста нагрузки или каких нибудь тяжелых аналитических запросов в базу? (просто время больно ровное для случайных падений)

Comment: Проблема ушла сама по себе после выхода mongodb 4.0.1. Что я только не делал, что только не изменял, в самой монге была проблема. На одном из форумов сказали что данная проблема уже была ранее, и стоит просто подождать выхода новый версии.